# Android Beacon Library, Null Object Reference when calling startRangingBeaconsInRegion

Tags: java, android, altbeacon

I'm developing an android app using beacon library, part of this app is about to search for a specific beacon via its minor ID (which is inserted by user via dialog).

if I write everything in the same activity things works fine but I'd like to keep dialogs separate in an external pure java class, so in the activity implementing BeaconConsumer I added a "method" creating and binding the beacon manager.

```
public class Activity03 extends AppCompatActivity
    implements BeaconConsumer, RangeNotifier {

    ...

    public void scanForBeacon(Context context, String selectedMinorId){
        beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(context);

        beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser()
            .setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24"));

        Identifier minorIdFilter = Identifier.parse(selectedMinorId);

        myRegion = new Region(
            "my_region",
             null,
             null,
             minorIdFilter);

        beaconManager.bind((BeaconConsumer) context);
    }
    ...
}
```

The point is that when calling **startRangingBeaconsInRegion**, i got:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(org.altbeacon.beacon.Region)' on a null object reference

The sequence is:
1. the user is asked (via GoogleApiClient) to switch on BLE and localization
2. inside **onActivityResult** the dialog for inserting minor ID is picked from the java class **DialogUtilities**
`DialogUtilities.showSelectionDialog(Activity03.this);`
3. pressing the button dialog is dismissed, an instance of the BeaconConsumer activity is created and the method called:
`Activity03 a03 = new  Activity03();
a03.scanForBeacon(context, minorId);`
4. when the **onBeaconServiceConnect()** is called I got null object reference on the line of **startRangingBeaconsInRegion**

```
@Override
public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {
    try {
        beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(myRegion);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I'm new of java and android but it doesn't seems to me that problem is about the Region because I've the same response even if I set to null all the Identifiers so I cannot understand why null reference.
Is it possible that I create two different BeaconMangers because of the activity's istance I return by Dialog ? If so how I can solve it?
If not, how to avoid this null object reference?
Thanks in advance

**EDIT**
BeaconManager declaration

```
public class Activity03 extends AppCompatActivity implements BeaconConsumer, RangeNotifier {
    static final int REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS = 1000;

    private BeaconManager beaconManager;
    private Region myRegion;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_03);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
          @Override
          super.onResume();
          PermissionsUtilities.switchLocationAndBluetooth(Activity03.this);

    }


    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        final LocationSettingsStates states = LocationSettingsStates.fromIntent(data);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS:
                switch (resultCode) {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                          DialogUtilities.showSensorSelectionDialog(Activity03.this);
                    break;
                case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                    ...
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the code below to avoid null pointer exception:

```
  beaconManager.setRangeNotifier(new RangeNotifier() {
              @Override
              public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection beacons, Region region) {
                  if (beacons.size() > 0) {
                      Log.i(TAG, "The first beacon I see is about "+beacons.iterator().next().getDistance()+" meters away.");
                  }
              }
          });

          try {
              beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(new Region("myRangingUniqueId", null, null, null));
          } catch (RemoteException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, I quickly rearranged my code according to your suggestion and got null pointer exception on `setrangeNotifier`; besides I also got that using `setRangeNotifier` in that way is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

The question does not show the declaration of `beaconManager` and how it is scoped, so it is hard to say the exact cause.

Two tips:

1. The `BeaconManager` is a singleton, meaning there is one instance per Java process.  So you can always get this instance from within an Activity like this: `BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this).startRangingBeaconsInRegion(myRegion);`
2. Manually constructing a new Activity instance as shown below generally will not work in Android programming.  You must create new Activity instance using an `Intent`.  In your case I suspect you may not want to create a new Activity instance at all but to get a reference to the existing one.  This may be unrelated to what you are asking, but it will certainly need to be changed: `Activity03 a03 = new  Activity03();
   a03.scanForBeacon(context, minorId);`

Comment: really thanks for your prompt reply and your suggestions. See above I edited my question. I'll also retry getting new activity reference by `Intent`.